# jQuery Complex selector with mid-wild card?

Tags: jquery, filter, tags, wildcard

I have a series of INPUT tags with this id structure.

```
id="menu_popSearch_chk1_I"
id="menu_popSearch_chk2_I"
id="menu_popSearch_chk3_I"
```

Etc. HOWEVER, so I do not want these

```
id="menu_popSearch_chk1_S"
id="menu_popSearch_chk2_S"
id="menu_popSearch_chk3_S"
```

Is there a 'wildcard' kind of feature where I can get the first set, but not the second set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('input[id$=_I]')
```

read [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeEndsWith#attributevalue)

EDIT:
or maybe you could do

```
$('input[id^=menu_popSearch]').not('input[id$=_S]')
```

EDIT 2:
okay as you keep refining the question I'll try to keep up

```
$('input[id^=menu_popSearch][id$=_I]')
```

read [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeMultiple#attributeFilter1attributeFilter2attributeFilterN) now

Comment: But there are other items with _I endings I would need all the elements which start with menu_popSearch and end with _I